# Duplicate row in Pandas dataframe based on condition, then update a new column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like :

[image]

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'qty': [10,7,2,1],
                   'status 1': [5,2,2,0],
                   'status 2': [3,2,0,1],
                   'status 3': [2,3,0,0]
                   })
```

Each row has a qty of items. These items have one status (1,2 or 3).

So qty = sum of values of status 1,2,3.

I would like to :

1. Duplicate each row by the "qty" column
2. Then edit 3 status (or update a new column), to get just 1 status.

The output should look like this:

[image]

Edit: the order is not important, but I will need to keep other columns of my initial df.

My (incomplete) solution so far - I found a way to duplicate the rows using this :

```
df2= df2.loc[df2.index.repeat(df2['qty'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

But I can't find a way to fill the status.

Do I need to use a for loop approach to fill the status?

Should I do this transform in 1 or 2 steps?

Something like: for each initial row, the n first rows take the first status, where n is the value of status 2....

The output could maybe looks like :

[image]

Edit1 : Thank you for your answers !

Last question : now I'm trying to integrate this to my actual df. What is the best approach to apply these methods to my df who contains many other column ?

I will answer my last question :

1. Split df in 2: `dfstatus` and `dfwithoutstatus`, keeping the qty column in both
2. Apply one of your method on the `dfstatus`
3. Apply my method on the `dfwithoutstatus` (a simple duplication)
4. Merge on index

Thank you all for your answers.

Best

Comment: Is order important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

E = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(df.shape[1] - 1, dtype=int))
result = pd.DataFrame(
    df['qty'].reindex(df.index.repeat(df['qty'])).reset_index(drop=True),
)
result[df.columns[1:]] = pd.concat(
    [E.reindex(E.index.repeat(df.iloc[i, 1:]))
     for i in range(len(df))],
).reset_index(
    drop=True,
)
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> result
    qty  status 1  status 2  status 3
0    10         1         0         0
1    10         1         0         0
2    10         1         0         0
3    10         1         0         0
4    10         1         0         0
5    10         0         1         0
6    10         0         1         0
7    10         0         1         0
8    10         0         0         1
9    10         0         0         1
10    7         1         0         0
11    7         1         0         0
12    7         0         1         0
13    7         0         1         0
14    7         0         0         1
15    7         0         0         1
16    7         0         0         1
17    2         1         0         0
18    2         1         0         0
19    1         0         1         0
```

Comment: I think your approach is the best in terms of resources consumption, I am actually working on another one but yours is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
(df[['qty']].join(df.iloc[:,1:].stack()
.map(lambda x: list(range(1,x+1)))
.explode()
.dropna()
.fillna(0)
.to_frame()
.assign(cc = lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
.set_index('cc',append=True)[0]
.unstack(level=1)
.droplevel(1)
.fillna(0)
.astype(bool)
.astype(int))
.reset_index(drop=True))
```

or with using `np.identity()`

```
cols = ['status 1','status 2','status 3']

(df[['qty']].join(
    df[cols]
    .stack()
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(np.identity(len(x)),x,axis=0)))
    .droplevel(1)
    .set_axis(cols,axis=1)))
```

or

```
l = df[cols].apply(lambda x: np.repeat(np.identity(len(x)),x,axis=0),axis=1).rename('t').explode()
df[['qty']].join(pd.DataFrame(l.tolist(),index = l.index))
```

Output:

```
    qty  status 1  status 2  status 3
0    10         1         0         0
1    10         1         0         0
2    10         1         0         0
3    10         1         0         0
4    10         1         0         0
5    10         0         1         0
6    10         0         1         0
7    10         0         1         0
8    10         0         0         1
9    10         0         0         1
10    7         1         0         0
11    7         1         0         0
12    7         0         1         0
13    7         0         1         0
14    7         0         0         1
15    7         0         0         1
16    7         0         0         1
17    2         1         0         0
18    2         1         0         0
19    1         0         1         0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using this.
Instead of repeating on df['qty'], repeat on the status themselves, the concatenate the results and sort:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'qty': [10,7,2,1],
                   'status 1': [5,2,2,0],
                   'status 2': [3,2,0,1],
                   'status 3': [2,3,0,0]
                   })
cols = ['status 1', 'status 2', 'status 3']

df_out = pd.concat([df.loc[df.index.repeat(df[col]), [col]+['qty']].reset_index()
 for col in cols], ignore_index=True).sort_values(['index']+cols)

df_out[cols] = df_out[cols].notna().astype(int)

df_out[['qty']+cols]
```

Output:

```
    qty  status 1  status 2  status 3
0    10         1         0         0
1    10         1         0         0
2    10         1         0         0
3    10         1         0         0
4    10         1         0         0
9    10         0         1         0
10   10         0         1         0
11   10         0         1         0
15   10         0         0         1
16   10         0         0         1
5     7         1         0         0
6     7         1         0         0
12    7         0         1         0
13    7         0         1         0
17    7         0         0         1
18    7         0         0         1
19    7         0         0         1
7     2         1         0         0
8     2         1         0         0
14    1         0         1         0
```

Answer (score 1):

hardcoded, but a more human readable approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'qty': [10,7,2,1],
                   'status 1': [5,2,2,0],
                   'status 2': [3,2,0,1],
                   'status 3': [2,3,0,0]
                   })
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df.columns)

cnt = 0
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    s_one = row['status 1']
    s_two = row['status 2']
    s_three = row['status 3']
    while s_one > 0:
        df2.loc[cnt] = [row['qty'],1,0,0]
        s_one-=1
        cnt+=1
    while s_two > 0:
        df2.loc[cnt] = [row['qty'],0,1,0]
        s_two-=1
        cnt+=1
    while s_three > 0:
        df2.loc[cnt] = [row['qty'],0,0,1]
        s_three-=1
        cnt+=1

print(df2)
```

same output.

Answer (score 1):

**Proposed code :**

This approach uses a trick (matrix identity)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'qty': [10,7,2,1],
                   'status 1': [5,2,2,0],
                   'status 2': [3,2,0,1],
                   'status 3': [2,3,0,0]
                   })

cols = df.columns[1:4]
# Define a boolean identity matrix (Trick 1)
ident = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(len(cols)).astype(bool))

# Trick 2 is to repeat rows 3 times before calculation
rep = df.loc[df.index.repeat(3)]

def func(g):
   ident.index, ident.columns = g.index, g.columns
   return (g.where(ident, 0)
            .applymap(lambda e: int(e)*[1] if e>0 else e))

# Break in matrix groups 3X3
rep[cols] = rep.groupby(rep.index).apply(lambda g: func(g[cols]))

# Explode lists
for c in rep.columns:
   rep = rep.explode(c)

# Deletes 0-valued rows
rep = rep[rep[cols].sum(axis=1) > 0].reset_index(drop=True)

print(rep)
```

**Results :**

```
    qty status 1 status 2 status 3
0    10        1        0        0
1    10        1        0        0
2    10        1        0        0
3    10        1        0        0
4    10        1        0        0
5    10        0        1        0
6    10        0        1        0
7    10        0        1        0
8    10        0        0        1
9    10        0        0        1
10    7        1        0        0
11    7        1        0        0
12    7        0        1        0
13    7        0        1        0
14    7        0        0        1
15    7        0        0        1
16    7        0        0        1
17    2        1        0        0
18    2        1        0        0
19    1        0        1        0
```